# How to Identify Tapped UIImage in UIImage array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I am populating UIImage array with code and adding them into UIScrollView successfully. I would like to identify the image tapped so I can run an action accordingly.

I appreciate your guidance and time.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped(_:)))
    }

    func loadImagePicker(){

    var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    let imageWidth: CGFloat = 100.0
    let imageHeight: CGFloat = 100.0

    for x in 0...2 {
        let image = UIImage(named: "item\(x).png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myData.images1.append(imageView)

        var newX: CGFloat = 0.0

        newX = 10 + imageWidth * CGFloat(x) + (10 * CGFloat(x))

        contentWidth += newX

        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: newX, y: scrollView.frame.size.height, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    }

    print(myData.images1.count)

    scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

    imagePickerView.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add gesture recognizer to your imageView just like following:

```
    //Instance Variable
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped(_:)))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    func loadImagePicker(){

        // .....

        for 0..<2 { //Assuming there are two images

        // .....
        // .....

        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        }
    }

    func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let tappedImageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
        let index = tappedImageView.tag // Do anything with the index by using it in your array

    }
```

Comment: Hello Badhan, thank you for the response. First, there are three images on loop it counts 0 as well. I have tried to print index. So, my three images loads, and your code recognize the click on the ONLY last one and it prints/tags as 0. Could you help me why it does that?

Comment: Oh I realized my loop does not add imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer) to all images. Cannot figure out why though. Only executes once. Thats why only it is tagged once. But I can see the images in the scrollview so they are there.

Comment: Okay now pls try putting the gesture initialization code into your for loop instead of an instance variable.

Comment: Badhan, this worked! Thank you so much. But, it still prints same tag which is 0. Although, I have managed to get the result I wanted without using tag. Again, thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your `tapGestureRecognizer` global or move it to your `loadImagePicker` function.
2. After setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true, add the gesture
   recogniser to the `imageView` by calling
   `imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)`.
3. Then implement the `imageTapped` function which accepts a sender of type `UITapGestureRecognizer`
4. Finally in the imageTapped function, access the UIImageView that was tapped by calling `sender as? UIImageView`